# vb.net - passing parameter to an application which is already running

Tags: vb.net, parameters

I have two applications and I need to be able to pass parameters between them.

Normally I would tackle this using **Process.start** from the 'sending' app to call the 'receiving' app and pass some arguments and then using **Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()** to parse the arguments in the load event  of the 'receiving' app and loop through them etc, but this is slightly different as in this case the 'receiving' app is a single instance application and will already be running, so I'm not sure how best to approach this.

Could someone nudge me in the right direction please? :)

Comment: @GSerg I did think about opening a local socket and using TCPClient/TCPListener etc, but it felt a little overkill for what i was looking to achieve, so i dismissed the idea in the hopes of finding something more simplistic... something which might not exist I guess?

Comment: @John If you want something simple, in the sense of "something known", you can also use a file (e.g. in combination with FileSystemWatcher) as a place for data exchange. But that is very limited and in the longer term you will be better off with GSerg's proposal.